# Converting a dialogue tibble to .txt, and back again

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, stringr, google-language-api

I want to take a tibble that represents dialogue and turn it into a .txt that can be manually edited in a text editor and then returned to a tibble for processing.

The key challenge I've had is separating the blocks of text in a way that they can be re-imported to a similar format after editing while preserving the "Speaker" designation.

Speed is important as the volume of files and the length of each text segment are large.

Here's the input tibble:

```
tibble::tribble(
    ~word, ~speakerTag,
   "been",          1L,
  "going",          1L,
     "on",          1L,
    "and",          1L,
   "what",          1L,
   "your",          1L,
  "goals",          1L,
   "are.",          1L,
  "Yeah,",          2L,
     "so",          2L,
     "so",          2L,
   "John",          2L,
    "has",          2L,
     "15",          2L
  )
```

Here's the desired output in a .txt:

```
###Speaker 1###
been going on and what your goals are.
###Speaker 2###
Yeah, so so John has 15
```

Here's the desired return after correcting errors manually:

```
    ~word, ~speakerTag,
   "been",          1L,
  "going",          1L,
     "on",          1L,
    "and",          1L,
   "what",          1L,
   "your",          1L,
  "goals",          1L,
   "in",            1L,
   "r",             1L,
  "Yeah,",          2L,
     "so",          2L,
     "so",          2L,
   "John",          2L,
    "hates",        2L,
     "50",          2L
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to add Speaker name `"\n"` at the start of each `speakerTag`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

setDT(df)[, word := replace(word, 1, paste0("\n\nSpeaker", 
            first(speakerTag), '\n\n', first(word))), rleid(speakerTag)]
```

We can write this in text file using

```
writeLines(paste(df$word, collapse = " "), 'Downloads/temp.txt')
```

It looks like this :

```
cat(paste(df$word, collapse = " "))

#Speaker1
#
#been going on and what your goals are. 
#
#Speaker2
#
#Yeah, so so John has 15
```

To read it back in R, we can do :

```
read.table('Downloads/temp.txt', sep="\t", col.names = 'word') %>%
    mutate(SpeakerTag = replace(word, c(FALSE, TRUE), NA)) %>%
    fill(SpeakerTag) %>%
    slice(seq(2, n(), 2)) %>%
    separate_rows(word, sep = "\\s") %>%
    filter(word != '')

#    word SpeakerTag
#1   been   Speaker1
#2  going   Speaker1
#3     on   Speaker1
#4    and   Speaker1
#5   what   Speaker1
#6   your   Speaker1
#7  goals   Speaker1
#8   are.   Speaker1
#9  Yeah,   Speaker2
#10    so   Speaker2
#11    so   Speaker2
#12  John   Speaker2
#13   has   Speaker2
#14    15   Speaker2
```

Obviously we can remove `"Speaker"` part in `SpeakerTag` column if it is not needed.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post an answer. A key part of my problem is the need to differentiate the speaker on the output .txt (for edits to the transcript), and then a procedure to re-upload. Your suggestions are moving me towards this solution, but I'm still struggling on how to output a .txt like the one I mentioned, and then read it back in for analysis. There will indeed be multiple exchanges between speaker 1 and speaker 2 throughout dialogue (switching back and forth).

Comment: I am not sure if I follow. Why do you need to read from text again? If you use the `data.table` answer the `df` you have at the end is what you want right? and you can use that to write the text file?

Comment: The data is coming from an automated audio transcription from Google Speech to text . The transcription makes errors. I want a .txt for manual review of file to correct errors, and then I want a tibble for analysis. So work flow would be, google->R->manual edit->R.

Comment: In this chain `google->R->manual edit->R` if everything is correct in your `manual edit` step, you go back to previous `R` step because it is the same data. You don't need to read the data from txt to R again. Although, I get what you mean and intend to do meaning if you do some manual changes in the text file you need to read it back in R.

Comment: Here is a step closer to desired output:

setDT(df)[, word := replace(word, .N, paste0(last(word), "\n\n")),
          rleid(speakerTag)]

setDT(df)[, word := replace(word, 1,paste0("Speaker",first(speakerTag),"\n\n",first(word))),
          rleid(speakerTag)]
cat(paste(df$word, collapse = " "))

Comment: Yes so question now is how to take that .txt and read it in to look like original tibble.

Comment: would the `word` column always contain a single word?

Comment: Yes the word column always has 1 word.

Comment: Hrmmm that worked in the reprex but not in the real data. Would there be a way to designate the "Speaker 1" using an identifiable string that could be used to rebuild the columns word/speaker.